# Loading Database Image in List App is Stuck

Tags: java, android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I have save image path in database and image save in folder. Displaying image in list view app is stuck and slow. I not understand how to resolve this issue.

I am using following code:

```
strContactImage = customer.getPhotoPath();
Bitmap decodedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strContactImage);
customerImage.setImageBitmap(decodedImage);
```

`customer.getPhotoPath()` gets folder photo path image, and displays it properly, but when I added more than 20 records app slows down, and gets stuck.

Comment: You need to decode Bitmap in background thread

Comment: You need to use Picasso or Glide or Universal Image Loader library for better caching and loading.

Comment: convert into uri from path and set into imageview

Answer (score 0):

Use uri to set image into image view instead of decoding into bitmap...

```
strContactImage = customer.getPhotoPath(); 
Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(new File(strContactImage));
// Set the uri into ImageView
customerImage.setImageURI(uri);
```

It might help you...

Comment: have u put android:largeHeap="true" into manifest file inside application tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any image caching library, here is the example of Picasso

```
strContactImage = customer.getPhotoPath();

Picasso.with(context)
   .load(new File(strContactImage))
   .into(customerImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

check the size of the images they can effect the memory and make the app stuck and slow if they are take a lot of memory !

to fix that

### take a look here

[Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

and check the method `calculateInSampleSize()` and `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource()`

`it’s not worth loading a 1024x768 pixel image into memory if it will eventually be displayed in a 128x96 pixel thumbnail in an ImageView.`

and you can use library that can help you to load image and they will take care about the memory usage and loading the image into Your View

**Library** :

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

example :

```
Picasso.with(context).load(file).into(imageview);
```

[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

example :

```
GlideApp.with(context).load(file).into(imageview);
```

### Tools - check this for more about :

[TinyPNG - Smart PNG and JPEG compression](https://tinypng.com/)

[Optimizilla](http://optimizilla.com/)